# how to make an incrementing numeric String as an id?

Tags: java, string, auto-increment

Hi i have been trying to find a way to create an ID in a class that is a String and has numeric values that icrement for every instance of the class that is created. I have found guides that shows me how to do it with integer but I want to use string. I'm at a loss as to how im going to do this.

```js
 import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Order {
  
 private String orderID;
 
    Order(String orderID) {
  setOrderID(orderID); 
 }
 
 public void setOrderID(String orderID) {
  this.orderID=orderID;
 }
 
   }
```

Comment: This looks like Java, no JavaScript.

Comment: Why would you want to use a string when an integer is more suitable?

Comment: if you're determined to use a String for the variable, you should generate the id as an int or long then use String.valueOf() to store it in this class as a String

Comment: use static int counter = 0 and increment it in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of the object is independent of the others. Therefore there is no way for the Order object to magically have a numerical value that is one higher than the previous instance you created without you assigning it yourself. If you have a loop with an incrementing index, you can successively insert them into a list. But, to do it with a String, you must convert the index to a String first. This is how I would do it:

Output:

```
OrderID: 0
OrderID: 1
OrderID: 2
OrderID: 3
OrderID: 4
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class F {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    Order order;
    String orderID;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      orderID = Integer.toString(i);        // Convert the index to a String
      order = new Order(orderID);           // Instantiate a new Order object with the String
      orders.add(order);                    // Add the String to the list
    }

    // Loop through the list
    for (Order o : orders) {
      System.out.println(o.getOrderID());
    }

  }
}

class Order {

    private String orderID;

    Order(String orderID) {
        setOrderID(orderID);
    }

    public void setOrderID(String orderID) {
        this.orderID=orderID;
    }

  // Getter method
  public String getOrderID() {
    return this.orderID;
  }

 }
```

Comment: the Order class is going into a hashmap in a class that is called Costumer.
so i hope not to use a for-loop but instead use something in the style of.
String orderID = (Integer.parseInt(version.substring(1,version.length()))+1); i am lost as to how to implement this
instead. But

Answer (score 0):

As my understand, you need to use a static int variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static counter to your class and assign the value as a String if you realy want to use String:

```
public class Order {

    private static final int orderCount = 0;
    private final String orderID;

    Order() {
        this.orderCount++;
        this.orderID = String.valueOf(this.orderCount);
    }

}
```

Comment: this seems like it might work for what im trying to do, if i get it to work.
maybe i should have written this but the reason i want to have the attribute as a String is that i don't want it to be applicable to mathematical formulas. Also my university professor demans it haha :)

Comment: Sounds like a really terrible and unnecessary solution for something that just is not a problem. If you write the code, you are in charge of what the attribute is used for, it is not like you'll "accidentally" use it in any mathematical formulas unless you write the specific code for this. I would keep it as a private integer, and if you need to expose it as a string, use a getter that does `String.valueOf`.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Of course the solution is not ideal and in a real world situation it simply wouldn't make any sense, but as he mentioned it is for his university and i guess this is simply for lerning purposes